# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/plus/webapp/PlusConfiguration

Tags: jetty, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

I was following the tutorial from the [Scalatra docs](http://www.scalatra.org/getting-started/first-project.html), installed the Consript and Giter8 and initialized the project using g8 as described. However when I cannot start the Jetty container using `container:start` as I am getting following exception:

```
[error] (container:start) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/plus/webapp/PlusConfiguration
```

I haven't made any changes to the project generated by Giter. The version of `java` and `javac` executables is 1.7.0_65 (Sun).

These are the library dependencies from `build.scala`:

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.6" % "runtime",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.1.3.v20140225" % "container",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"))
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got same problem and spent several hours to find out how to fix it. But nothing resulted. :( So I have to check out the Scalatra template.

In https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8, there a some modified build.scala at few days ago. [the version of "jetty-webapp" was changed from "8.1.8.v20121106" to "9.1.3.v20140225"](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8/commit/03d730c5020a3bfd9ba82ecb01a3bfbf47d61a03).

Then I modify version of jetty-webapp to previous version in my project's build.scala file and application runs well. :)

I'll raise issue for this problem.

Good luck.

Added > the template patched now and container:start works fine. :)

Comment: Actually this answer is perfect. Firstly it's nice to see that I am not the only one who encountered the same problem - and when it comes even with a working solution, it's all I need for now. Thank you ACodFarmer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For scalatra 2.3.0 its this:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.1.5.v20140505" % "container",
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-plus" % "9.1.5.v20140505" % "container",
"javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0"
```